# How to fix duplicate wireless taskbar display?

Tags: 18.04, wireless, lubuntu, broadcom, taskbar

I followed [the instructions to install the driver for `BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)`, `firmware-b43-installer`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers). However, now my wireless module (should I call it that?) is displaying twice in my taskbar. What caused this taskbar issue? How do I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Right-clicking the left wireless icon (4-bars signal strength icon) shows network connections, whereas right-clicking the right wireless icon (same icon design) shows Indicator Applet / Panel settings. Thus, according to #lubuntu's wxl on Freenode, the left is the nm-applet (Network Manager applet) whereas the right is the Indicator applet. So there is no bug, merely a counter-intuitive design for lxde.